# Integral with Leibniz Rules

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find derivative of the following integral with respect to $b$ which is a function itself,
$$
\int_{\underline{x}}^{b_*^{-1}(b)}(v(x,\alpha)-b)f_{Y_1}(\alpha|x)d\alpha
$$

where $f_{Y_{1}}$ is the pdf of $F_{Y_1}$. Note that $b_*$ is not equal to $b$. I have tried to use Leibniz rule and derivative of the inverse but could not reach any meaningful result. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we do not know the situation from which this integral has sprung, we cannot understand what "meaningfull" may mean here. So what's wrong with Leibniz rule
$$\frac {\partial} {\partial b}\int_{\underline{x}}^{b_*^{-1}(b)}(v(x,\alpha)-b)f_{Y_1}(\alpha|x)d\alpha = $$
$$=(v(x,b_*^{-1}(b))-b)f_{Y_1}(b_*^{-1}(b)|x)\frac {\partial b_*^{-1}(b)} {\partial b} + \int_{\underline{x}}^{b_*^{-1}(b)}\frac {\partial} {\partial b}(v(x,\alpha)-b)f_{Y_1}(\alpha|x)d\alpha$$
$$=(v(x,b_*^{-1}(b))-b)f_{Y_1}(b_*^{-1}(b)|x)\frac {\partial b_*^{-1}(b)} {\partial b} - \int_{\underline{x}}^{b_*^{-1}(b)}\frac {\partial} {\partial b}(bf_{Y_1}(\alpha|x))d\alpha$$

$$=(v(x,b_*^{-1}(b))-b)f_{Y_1}(b_*^{-1}(b)|x)\frac {\partial b_*^{-1}(b)} {\partial b}- \big[F_{Y_1}(b_*^{-1}(b)|x)-F_{Y_1}(\underline{x}|x)\Big] $$

where $F()$ is the cdf.